# How can we add product in cart using it's SKU number?

Tags: shopify

I am currently using ajax api `/cart/add.js` to add product in cart like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST', 
   url: '/cart/add.js',
   dataType: 'json', 
   data: {quantity: 1,id: gift_variant_id},
   error:function(){ console.log('error'); }
 });
```

is there any way I can add product in cart using product sku number?

because `{quantity: 1,sku: sku_number}` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is only **one** way to add a product to the cart, and that is by providing a valid variant ID.

A SKU is not unique in Shopify, it is simply a descriptive string value, meaning a shop with 1000 products could theoretically assign them all a single SKU with no errors. Hence, that is a problem. So rule is, use a valid ID.